# What's the difference between <fragment_name >$key and <fragment_name >$data in react relay fragment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I'm learning react relay library, when reading doc [Relay - A Guided Tour - Fragments](https://relay.dev/docs/guided-tour/rendering/fragments/#rendering-fragments), I am confused by this part:

```
Relay will automatically generate Flow types for any declared 
fragments when the compiler is run, so you can use these types to 
declare the type for your Component's props.

The generated Flow types include a type for the fragment reference, 
which is the type with the $key suffix: <fragment_name>$key, and a 
type for the shape of the data, which is the type with the $data 
suffix: <fragment_name>$data; these types are available to import 
from files that are generated with the following name: 
<fragment_name>.graphql.js.
```

1. What does `fragment reference` mean? Does it mean the generated flow type of this fragment (`UserComponent_user`)? Or the generated flow type of the query contain/use the fragment (`User`)?
2. What's the `type` with $key suffix? The fragment or the query?
3. What's the `type` with $data suffix? The fragment or the query?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example

```
import type {UserComponent_user$key} from 'UserComponent_user.graphql';

const React = require('React');

const {graphql, useFragment} = require('react-relay');

type Props = {
  user: UserComponent_user$key,
};

const userFragment = graphql`
  fragment UserFragment_user on User {
    name
    age
    profile_picture(scale: 2) {
      uri
    }
  }
`;

function UserComponent(props: Props) {
  const data = useFragment(
    userFragment, props.user
  );

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <div>
        <img src={data.profile_picture?.uri} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

module.exports = UserComponent;
```

Remember that fragments are reusable units in GraphQL and they can't be fetched by themselves. So we need to include it in a query.Note that a single fragment can still be included by multiple queries.

```
/**
 * App.react.js
 *
 * Query Component
 */

import type {AppQuery} from 'AppQuery.graphql';
import type {PreloadedQuery} from 'react-relay';

const React = require('React');
const {graphql, usePreloadedQuery} = require('react-relay');

const UserComponent = require('./UserComponent.react');

type Props = {
  appQueryRef: PreloadedQuery<AppQuery>,
}

function App({appQueryRef}) {
  const data = usePreloadedQuery<AppQuery>(
    graphql`
      query AppQuery($id: ID!) {
        user(id: $id) {
          name

          # Include child fragment:
          ...UserComponent_user
        }
      }
    `,
    appQueryRef,
  );

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{data.user?.name}</h1>
      {/* Render child component, passing the fragment reference: */}
      <UserComponent user={data.user} />
    </>
  );
}
```

You can see AppQuery is getting the data for included fragment which is under `user` field. Now, inorder to get that data, we need a pointer to it. Fragment reference is nothing, but that pointer.
We pass `data.user`(this refers to fragment spread in main query and it acts as fragment reference with $key flow type) into the UserComponent and UserComponent applies fragment definition into that key and get the data.

The type with $key prefix is nothing but a flow type which is the type for fragment reference.

The type with $data prefix is nothing but a flow type which is the type for data that is in fragment definition.